# nasm assembly linux timer or sleep

Tags: linux, assembly, timer, sleep, nasm

I'm trying to find a way to make my code wait for two seconds before proceeding. I'm using nasm for Linux in protected mode, so I can only use int 80h. I found a `syscall` called "`alarm`" (27) and another called "`pause`" (29). However, when I try to use those, the program waits and finishes instead of continuing execution. I've also found another `syscall`, sigaction, which changes the behavior of a signal (so I think it can be used to make the program ignore the signal generated by alarm instead of exiting) but I didn't quite understand how sigaction works. Thanks for any help.
Useful links:http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and follow the links to other man pages there.

Comment: One correction, you are doing userspace programming in nasm, so you are not in protected mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a system call for sleeping the program, [`sys_nanosleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep):

```
 sys_nanosleep : eax = 162, ebx = struct timespec *, ecx = struct timespec *
```

this `struct timespec` structure has two members:

```
 ;; This is for 32-bit.  Note that x86-64 uses 2x 64-bit members
tv_sec   ; 32 bit seconds
tv_nsec  ; 32 bit nanoseconds
```

this structure can be declared in nasm as:

```
section .data

  timeval:
    tv_sec  dd 0
    tv_usec dd 0
```

and then you sets the values and call it as:

```
mov dword [tv_sec], 5
mov dword [tv_usec], 0
mov eax, 162
mov ebx, timeval
mov ecx, 0
int 0x80
```

the program then will sleep for 5 seconds. A complete example:

```
global  _start

section .text
_start:

  ; print "Sleep"
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, bmessage
  mov edx, bmessagel
  int 0x80

  ; Sleep for 5 seconds and 0 nanoseconds
  mov dword [tv_sec], 5
  mov dword [tv_usec], 0
  mov eax, 162
  mov ebx, timeval
  mov ecx, 0
  int 0x80

  ; print "Continue"
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, emessage
  mov edx, emessagel
  int 0x80

  ; exit
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80

section .data

  timeval:
    tv_sec  dd 0
    tv_usec dd 0

  bmessage  db "Sleep", 10, 0
  bmessagel equ $ - bmessage

  emessage  db "Continue", 10, 0
  emessagel equ $ - emessage
```

Answer (score 2):

With NASM, if you are targeting Linux x86-64, you can simply do something similar to the following:

```
global _start

section .data

    timespec:
        tv_sec  dq 1
        tv_nsec dq 200000000

section .text

    _start:
        mov rax, 35
        mov rdi, timespec
        xor rsi, rsi        
        syscall
        ...
```

`35` corresponds to the 64-bit system call number for `sys_nanosleep` (as listed [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl)). If the call is interrupted, the remaining sleep time is written to the memory location pointed by register `rsi`; in this example `rsi` is set to 0 to ignore the value if it happens. This call will sleep for *tv_sec seconds + tv_nsec nanoseconds*, 1.2 seconds in the above code snippet.

More information about this system call can be found in the [nanosleep man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).