# Blinking char in Assembler Emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've been googling around and yet I didnt seem to find the code for this. I want to know if how can I make a character blink foe example "*". Thanks!

Comment: First print a character, then wait one second, then print a blank. Repeat this loop as often as you want. To find out how to wait one second, this question should give you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201955/how-to-set-1-second-time-delay-at-assembly-language-8086

Comment: so print a char, maybe print a blank to the position of the char?

Comment: Position the cursor in the same place and print the space char, then reposition the cursor to that same place again and print the character itself.  Incidentally, if this is an assignment for school, and you want to impress someone, perhaps the faculty member, you can also figure out a time slicing algorithm, and "fade out" the character by replacing the character with the empty space, then the character itself again, then the space again, and each time let the space character occupy the place on the screen just a little bit longer, until the space character hits 100% of the time.

Comment: Be aware that "printing" the backspace might result in an unexpected observation. I seem to remember that it was the same as a control character for a "ding" sound or something.

Comment: @User.1 Backspace isn't the same control code as a ding, it's actually the one after that. BEL is 7 and BS is 8.

Answer (score 1):

Additional solutions in combination with waiting one second are to invert the dots of the character, or with switching the foreground and background color, or within the textmode with using the blink attribute. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode

Comment: The blink attribute is not supported by emu8086.